# Deployment of Jar using Ant and OJDeploy for packaging ADF

Tags: ant, oracle-adf

I'm trying to Deploy a Jar File from an ANT script (with OjDeploy), which compiles successfully. But when I run the main project (Which has the Jar dependency), I get a huge incident, when I analysed the incident log, it says

```
"Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"
```

I analysed both the jar files (One generated by the ANT script and the other generated from Jdev). I couldn't find any difference b/w Manifest of those two jars. The other folders are also the same, In other words, both are almost the same, or I'm not able to figure out the difference between the two jar files generated.

I know, I'm missing something, config of build.xml or something, but not able to figure out the exact problem.

Thanks,

Shiva Shankar

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is not in the JAR file but rather in the project that consumes it.
Seems like the DB connection in that project is different than the one in your JAR project - which causes one of the tables that is needed in the DB not be found.

Comment: Hi Shay, Thanks for the response
Doesn't the JAR file use the DB connection inside the Main Project? Whenever we build an EAR file of the main project, there is only one connection.xml file in it. Or do I need to explicitly specify in the ant script for the JAR to use the DB connection of the main project? Are we sure that something someother config mis match is not causing this? Coz I've cross checked both the Jars and not found any difference..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to solve the problem. Not sure what was the cause of this issue, but a couple of changes made both to JAR/EAR build scripts set the things right

While building JAR files:

1. Uncheck "Make this the project build file" while creating the ANT build file, while the "Include Packaging Tasks (uses OjDeploy)" must be checked.
2. Remove "nocompile" parameter from  tag in the OjDeploy.

While Building EAR files:

1. Create EAR in the view controller project.
2. Go to the View Controller Project Properties-> Project Source Path -> Resources, remove the newly created build file dependency, which specifies that the build file is for the whole project and not for the individual project.
3. Remove "Project" parameter from  tag in the OjDeploy. (Ensures to build for the whole application)
4. Remove "nocompile" parameter from  tag in the OjDeploy.

These are the exhaustive set of changes, which I made to ensure the ANT files are building correctly, if you get any other errors after this EAR is deployed, then its definitely due to code, EO/VO or DB related.

Thanks for all the help!! 
Shiva Shankar